# How to overflow LWC component inside flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, flowscreen

I just want to ask how to overflow the dropdown list of lookup inside the flow. I have this LWC component embedded inside a screen flow (the lookup field) but instead of overflowing on my screen flow, it displays the dropdown inside LWC with a scrollbar on the right.

[image]

Here is my html code:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element" onmouseleave={toggleResult}  data-source="lookupContainer">      
        <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-selection">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-1">Service Ids:</label>
            <div class="lookupInputContainer slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox"> 
                <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">
                    <div class="searchBoxWrapper">
                        <lightning-input                   
                            type="search"
                            data-source="searchInputField"
                            dropdown-alignment="auto"
                            onclick={toggleResult}
                            onchange={handleKeyChange}
                            is-loading={isSearchLoading}
                            variant="label-hidden"
                            placeholder={placeholder}>
                        </lightning-input>  
                    </div>
                
            <!--Lookup Selected record pill container start-->  
                    <div class="pillDiv slds-hide">        
                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-combobox__input-entity-icon">
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:asset_object" size="x-small" alternative-text="icon"></lightning-icon>  
                        </span>
                        <input type="text"
                            id="combobox-id-1"
                            value={selectedRecord.Name}       
                            class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value"
                            readonly/>
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" title="Remove selected option">
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="x-small" alternative-text="close icon" onclick={handleRemove}></lightning-icon> 
                        </button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
        
                <!-- lookup search result part start-->
                <div style="margin-top:0px" id="listbox-id-5" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                        <template for:each={astList} for:item="obj">
                        <li key={obj.Id} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                            <div data-recid={obj.Id} onclick={handleSelectedRecord} class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
                                <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon" >
                                    <span class="slds-icon_container" >
                                        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:asset_object" size="small" alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>  
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                <span style="pointer-events: none;" class="slds-media__body" >
                                    <span  class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{obj.Name}
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        </template>
                    <!--ERROR msg, if there is no records..-->
                    <template if:false={hasRecords}>
                        <li class="slds-listbox__item" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">No Records Found....</li>
                    </template>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using any custom LWC component for the Lookup?

Comment: Yes, I am using LWC for the lookup

Comment: Where are you using the Screen Flow?

Comment: We are displaying the available assets under the drop down list and if the user selected a value, it will get the record id. It is working fine, but I just cannot overflow the lookup drop down outside screen flow.

Comment: Are you invoking the Flow directly from Quick Action? Or are you using any Aura Component to invoke the Flow?

Comment: I am using a button to invoke the flow. Like buttons you find in record (Edit, Delete, Clone).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not overwriting the `overflow` or `overflow-y` property in your css file. Also, make sure if `slds-scrollable` class is used anywhere as it also overwrites the `overflow` property.

You can use below css property to overflow the dropdown.

In HTML

```
<div class="slds-form-element custom-class-name" ...>
```

In CSS

```
.custom-class-name {
     overflow: initial !important;
     overflow-y: initial !important;
    }
```

---

Note: This will not work if you are using the Flow inside an Aura Component. There is a different workaround in that case.

Comment: hi Sneh, I tried using this solution and still it does not overflow within the screen flow.